# How to supply both named and free_form arguments to ansible ad-hoc?

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I ran across one of Ansible's modules that take free_form arguments along with named arguments - [`win_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_command_module.html#examples). A specific example is given, where a powershell script is provided on `stdin`:

```
- name: Run an executable and send data to the stdin for the executable
  win_command: powershell.exe -
  args:
    stdin: Write-Host test
```

I want to use this as a one-off task, so I want to use ad-hoc execution in the style of

```
ansible <host> -m <module> -a <args...>
```

Unfortunately, I see no info in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html) on how to deal with a module that requires specifying both free_form and named arguments. Does anyone know?

Putting the named arguments after the free_form argument puts everything in the free_form argument, resulting in powershell complaining about extraneous arguments

```
... -m win_command -a 'powershell - stdin=C:\some\script.ps1 -arg1 value_1 -arg2 value_2'
```

PS: I'm aware I could probably stuff both the script path and arguments in the free_form argument, but I am more interested in learning whether this is possible with ad-hoc, as the docs don't say either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test the `win_command` module directly, but with the `command` module, which is syntactically very similar, you can reproduce this:

```
- command: some_command
  args:
    chdir: /tmp
    creates: flagfile
```

Like this:

```
ansible -m command -a 'chdir=/tmp creates=flagfile some_command'
```

**Update**

Upon investigation...the problem you've encountered with `stdin` isn't a quoting issue;
 it's that when using the `k1=v1 k2=v2 somecommand` format of passing parameters to  e.g. the `command` module, Ansible only handles specific keys.  In [lib/ansible/parsing/splitter.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/parsing/splitter.py#L90) we see:

```py
if check_raw and k not in ('creates', 'removes', 'chdir', 'executable', 'warn'):
    raw_params.append(orig_x)
else:
    options[k.strip()] = unquote(v.strip())
```

That is, it only recognizes `creates`, `removes`, `chdir`, `executable`, and `warn` as module arguments. I would argue that this is a bug in Ansible. Adding support for the `stdin` argument is trivial, of course:

```py
if check_raw and k not in ('stdin', 'creates', 'removes', 'chdir', 'executable', 'warn'):
```

With this change, we can include `stdin` with spaces as expected:

```
$ ansible localhost -m command -a 'chdir=/tmp stdin="Hello world" sed s/Hello/Goodbye/'                                                                    
 [WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/lars/.ansible_hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Goodbye world
```

Comment: Well, in the powershell example both stdin and free_form need to have spaces in them, so I tried both obvious ways of quoting ( `'` inside `"` and the reverse). Neither of them work.

The first fails, trying to locate _stdin='Write-Host.exe"_ (yes, mismatching quotes), the second fails with _Illegal characters in path._

Comment: I've filed a [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/55921) that corrects this problem. We'll see where it goes.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with ansible architecture - does the issue in `splitter.py` affect the `win_command` module?
EDIT: The exact error reported is _Exception calling "HasExtension" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."_ and this occurs in [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/powershell/Ansible.ModuleUtils.CommandUtil.psm1)

Comment: This absolutely impacts the ability to pass the `stdin` argument to modules when running ad-hoc commands.  Without this patch, the `stdin=...` argument is interpreted as part of the command, which could easily lead to the error you're seeing. It's a single word patch; if you have the chance to try it out I would be interested in whether or not it resolves the issue.